# ST_Within incorrectly returns true when a point is outside a polygon

Tags: google-bigquery, gis, postgis

This query to determine whether a point is within a polygon...

```
SELECT ST_Within
(
    ST_GeogPoint(69.6, 21.1),
    ST_GeogFromText('POLYGON((67.8 23.4, 69 17, 72.8 16.9, 67.8 23.4))')
)
```

...returns TRUE in BigQuery.  This is an incorrect result.

The same query...

```
SELECT ST_Within
(
    ST_MakePoint(69.6, 21.1),
    'POLYGON((67.8 23.4, 69 17, 72.8 16.9, 67.8 23.4))'
)
```

...returns FALSE in PostGIS.  This is a correct result.

Answer (score 12):

This query gives you the `false` reply you were looking for:

```
SELECT ST_WITHIN(
  ST_GeogPoint(69.6, 21.1)
  , ST_GeogFromGeoJSON(
    '{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[67.8, 23.4], [69, 17], [72.8, 16.9], [67.8, 23.4]]]}'
))
```

What's the difference?

Let's check the docs:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_geogfromgeojson

> A BigQuery GEOGRAPHY has spherical geodesic edges, whereas a GeoJSON Geometry object explicitly has planar edges. To convert between these two types of edges, BigQuery adds additional points to the line where necessary so that the resulting sequence of edges remains within 10 meters of the original edge.

In fact, there's a really interesting tessellation happening to convert between both systems:

```
 SELECT ST_GeogFromGeoJSON(
   '{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[67.8, 23.4], [69, 17], [72.8, 16.9], [67.8, 23.4]]]}'
 )

 POLYGON((67.8 23.4, 67.875 23, 67.95 22.6, 68.025 22.2, 68.1 21.8, 68.175 21.4, 68.25 21, 68.325 20.6, 68.4 20.2, 68.475 19.8, 68.55 19.4, 68.625 19, 68.7 18.6, 68.775 18.2, 68.85 17.8, 68.925 17.4, 69 17, 69.2375 16.99375, 69.475 16.9875, 69.7125 16.98125, 69.95 16.975, 70.1875 16.96875, 70.425 16.9625, 70.6625 16.95625, 70.9 16.95, 71.1375 16.94375, 71.375 16.9375, 71.6125 16.93125, 71.85 16.925, 72.0875 16.91875, 72.325 16.9125, 72.5625 16.90625, 72.8 16.9, 72.64375 17.103125, 72.4875 17.30625, 72.33125 17.509375, 72.175 17.7125, 72.01875 17.915625, 71.8625 18.11875, 71.70625 18.321875, 71.55 18.525, 71.39375 18.728125, 71.2375 18.93125, 71.08125 19.134375, 70.925 19.3375, 70.76875 19.540625, 70.6125 19.74375, 70.45625 19.946875, 70.3 20.15, 70.14375 20.353125, 69.9875 20.55625, 69.83125 20.759375, 69.675 20.9625, 69.51875 21.165625, 69.3625 21.36875, 69.20625 21.571875, 69.05 21.775, 68.89375 21.978125, 68.7375 22.18125, 68.58125 22.384375, 68.425 22.5875, 68.26875 22.790625, 68.1125 22.99375, 67.95625 23.196875, 67.8 23.4))
```

Btw, from Earth Engine docs:

- https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/geometries_planar_geodesic

> A geometry created in Earth Engine is either geodesic (i.e. edges are the shortest path on the surface of a sphere) or planar (i.e. edges are the shortest path in a 2-D Cartesian plane). No one planar coordinate system is suitable for global collections of features, so Earth Engine's geometry constructors build geodesic geometries by default.

[image]

---

Now let's check PostGIS - which can work with Geometries and Geographies.

```
SELECT ST_CoveredBy (
    ST_MakePoint(69.6, 21.1),
    'POLYGON((67.8 23.4, 69 17, 72.8 16.9, 67.8 23.4))'
)    
false

SELECT ST_CoveredBy(
    ST_MakePoint(69.6, 21.1)::geography,
    'POLYGON((67.8 23.4, 69 17, 72.8 16.9, 67.8 23.4))'
)
true
```

(at the continental scale of this polygon: you really want to use geographies over geometries - even though the performance in PostGIS will be slower)

---

Back to BigQuery: What's the distance between Paris and LA?

```
SELECT ROUND(ST_Length(line)/1000,2) km
FROM (
  SELECT [
    ST_GeogFromGeoJSON('{"type": "LineString", "coordinates": [[-118.4079, 33.9434], [2.5559, 49.0083]]}')
    , ST_GEOGFROMTEXT('LINESTRING(-118.4079 33.9434, 2.5559 49.0083)')
  ] lines
), UNNEST(lines) line


km
10187.92     
9103.09
```

[image]

I just saved you 1084 km of travel by using a geodesic line.

Answer (score 1):

Google BigQuery is not using planar lines on the map, rather BigQuery Geography defines them as geodesic ones (more details in section "[Coordinate systems and edges](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/gis-data)")

So, if you will draw your polygon and point in [BigQuery GIS Data Visualization Tool](https://bigquerygeoviz.appspot.com/) - you will see that the point is inside the polygon

Answer (score 1):

When you plot this on Google Earth, it's outside the polygon.  Here's a screenshot and a kml file that contains both the polygon and that point.  Does that mean that Google Earth and the BigQuery GIS Data Visualization Tool use different coordinate systems?

[point outside polygon on Google Earth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkaYy.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Folder>
    <name>Temporary Places</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <Document>
        <name>Big Query ST_Within test.kml</name>
        <Style id="prelim">
            <LineStyle>
                <color>ff0000ff</color>
            </LineStyle>
            <PolyStyle>
                <color>4c0000ff</color>
            </PolyStyle>
        </Style>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Big Query ST_Within polygon</name>
            <styleUrl>#prelim</styleUrl>
            <Polygon>
                <tessellate>1</tessellate>
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            67.8,23.4,0 69,17,0 72.8,16.9,0 67.8,23.4,0 
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
    </Document>
    <Placemark>
        <name>Big Query ST_Within point</name>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>69.6,21.1,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
</Folder>
</kml>
```

Comment: thanks for the hints and picture! building on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52903062/132438

Comment: thanks to you, Felipe, for the illustrated explanation worthy of Popular Mechanics.  For the record, I tried using the miles you saved us to obtain a free ticket with the airlines, but they say they're already using Great Circle Routes.  Ah well, still worth the effort.